# Chrome seems to lock up Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome

For weeks now, every other day, my desktop running Windows 7 locks up and requires hitting the Reset button.

I notice that it's always while Chrome is running, and apparently always when there's a video playing. I suspect it's due to the Flash plug-in.

Does someone know of a way to investigate why Windows locks up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows can lock up for many reasons, and I think you've answered your own question - you have to keep an eye out for what creates the lock (patterns, programs, time of day, type of usage etc)! In this case, you've done that!

First you need to work out if the issue is Chrome, the plug in, Flash, the site or something else (or a combination)!!

So, things to try

Try a different browser for a few days
Don't watch any video for a few days whilst using Chrome
Try using Chrome in safe mode
Try Chrome and a video on a different site
Try Chrome with an HTML 5 video (not a flash video)

Comment: Keeping track of browser/plug-ins/etc. versions would be useful as well.

Comment: Thanks. It's not going to be easy doing the above. I'll see if Chrome includes some kind of watchdog.

Comment: Alas not @OverTheRainbow, but sadly these are the best ways to find out what the issue is.. trial and error!